# Processing a large dataset of nested data

Tags: yamldotnet

I have a rather large set of data which is structured in a somewhat unique fashion. It looks something like this:

```
foo:
- name: "some name"
  location: "some location"
  type: "someType"

  bar:
    - name: "A bar element"
      location: "location here"
      type: "someOtherType"
      attachments:
        - type: "attachmentTypeA"
          name: "Attachment name"
        - type: "attachmentTypeB"
          name: "Attachment name"

  baz:
    - name: "another name"
      location: "another location"
      type: "anotherType"

      qux:
        - name: "My name here"
          location: "My location here"
          type: "SomeOtherTypeHere"

          xyzzy:
            - name: "Another name here"
              location: "Another location here"
              type: "anotherTypeHere"

              bar:
                - name: "Some name here"
                  location: "Some location here"
                  type: "typeHere"
                  attachments:
                    - type: "attachmentTypeA"
                      name: "attachment name here"
                    - type: "attachmentTypeA"
                      name: "attachment name here"
                    - type: "attachmentTypeB"
                      name: "attachment name here"

                - name: "Another name here"
                  location: "Another location here"
                  type: "anotherTypeHere"
                  attachments:
                    - type: "attachmentTypeA"
                      name: "attachment name here"
                    - type: "attachmentTypeC"
                      name: "attachment name here"
                    - type: "attachmentTypeD"
                      name: "attachment name here"
    - name: "Another baz listing"
      location: "Baz location"
      type: "bazTypeHere"
```

So basically, you have "foo" at the top level (and there can be more than one foo, but always at the top level). In general, the structure is:

foo > baz > qux > xyzzy > bar

However, any of the sub elements can be at the root, or under foo, provided they are in order. So these are valid:

```
foo
  qux
    xyzzy
      bar
        attachments
      bar
        attachments
```

As is this:

```
foo
  baz
    qux
      xyzzy
        bar
          attachments
        bar
          attachments
  qux
    xyzzy
      bar
        attachments
      bar
        attachments
  xyzzy
    bar
      attachments
    bar
      attachments
```

And so on. It's whacky, I know. But that's the dataset I inherited.  I looked at the examples, in particular the DeserializeObjectGraph and LoadingAYamlStream examples. The DeserializeObjectGraph approach gets kind of crazy when the data is laid out like this. I finally gave up on it as it just got too hairy. The stream approach seems like a better fit, I think, but I'm running into troubles.

I am loading up the YAML as follows:

```
        string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText ( fileName );
        var input = new StringReader (contents);
        var yaml = new YamlStream ();
        yaml.Load (input);
```

As you can see, nothing fancy there. I'm just trying to get a "tree" of objects that I can then iterate through. I tried using the AllNodes property from the root node, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to iterate through them recursively in some manner than makes sense. I will also confess that I am a C# n00btard that is still learning (old C guy here), so bear with me!

Can anyone suggest an approach, or possibly some code or even pseudocode that might be able to help me out?

Comment: What is your goal, what kind of output do you expect from any code? E.G. I imagine you could use javascript in the browser to iterate through objects - it wouldn't take long to write that.

Comment: This is using YamlDotNet under Unity, so no browser involved. As I said, ideally, I would process it with YamlDotNet and end up with a tree that I could then sift through and work with. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Can you add the code that you used to deserialize the document ? This would help providing suggestions.

Comment: Antoine, thanks for the quick response! I added a code snippet and a bit more flavor to my original post. As you can see from it, there is nothing fancy there really. I just load the markup from a file. Now I just need to figure out how to iterate through them. That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: I should add, it isn't so much about the data structure I'm dealing with as it is I guess just how to iterate through them at a high level. I can recursively do it, if need be, just need to figure out the right syntax/constructs involved.

Comment: Also, the problem with taking the Deserialization approach is that the data I have in each file can differ dramatically from one to the next, unlike in your example for Deserialisation where each document might be an order receipt in the same format.

This is why I thought if I could just load up the YAML via the stream approach, I could process it myself in my own code. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Well, I had a bit of an epiphany and decided to try the Deserialisation approach again, and it worked this time. I would still like to know how to load up YAML and iterate through the nodes manually, though, if you have the time to chime in on it. Thanks!